# How do I set multiple existing columns in a dataframe to factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

Basically, suppose I have 10 columns (i.e. `a-j`) and columns `b` and `g` are the columns that are currently numeric and that I want to set to factors. How to set these specific columns as factors rather than doing `as.factor()` and adding them to my existing `dataframe` (my `dataframe` for this example is `dataInExample`)?

The libraries I am using are `dplyr` and `tidyverse`.

```
dataInExample <- as.factor(dataInExample$b) #rather than this and then add it again
dataInExample <- some R code that converts columns b and g to factors in dataInExample, would select() be used here? how would I then use it to convert these specific columns into factors without having to readd them to my data frame?
```

My original table (all columns except `b` and `g` are numeric; `b` and `g` have two levels representing high/low and good/bad, respectively):

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Not sure I follow... could you depict a small example of what your before/after tables would look like?

Comment: @DominicComtois my table example is there and essentially I want r to recognize that columns b and g specifically are factors and not numeric values. I am not changing the value of 1 to something like good and 0 bad, simply that they represent factors and that r treats them as factors instead of numeric

Comment: Are the current answers satisfactory? If yes, pls accept the best one, and if not, what is missing? Reading your comment, I wonder if you just want for instance `dat$b <- factor(dat$b, labels = c("good", "bad"))`?

Answer (score 2):

This should get what you need:

```
# load library
library(tidyverse)

# replicate example data
dat <- tibble::tribble(
         ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d, ~e, ~f, ~g, ~h, ~i, ~j,
         1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L,
         1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L
         )

# mutate across all of specified columns
dat |> 
  mutate(across(all_of(c("b","g")), as.factor))
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 10
      a b         c     d     e     f g         h     i     j
  <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 1         2     1     1     1 1         1     8     1
2     1 2         1     5     1     1 2         6     1     1
```

Comment: Not sure that's what the OP wants to do, but you could also find the names of columns having only 1's and 2's like this (however you'll run into problems if you don't have enough data points): `names(which(sapply(sapply(dat, unique), identical, c(1L,2L))))`

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse has the [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) syntax , which you can use to modify multiple variable at once. For example, you can select columns to change based on condition (e.g., all numeric variables), or specific column names or locations. Examples of each using the iris data are below.

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Convert all numeric columns to factor
numeric_to_factor = iris %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), factor))

# 2. Convert columns by name to factor
factor_cols = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
names_to_factor = iris %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(factor_cols), factor))

# 3. Convert columns 1 to 4 (location) to factor
factor_cols = 1:4
location_to_factor = iris %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(factor_cols), factor))
```

Comment: so using my code how would I select my specific columns? I am trying to follow the iris example provided but want two specific variables to become factors, they are in columns and not adjacent to each other.

Comment: The second example in @tauft answer seems to cover what you need. You just need a vector of the column names you want to convert.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in `across` is the columns to change, and the second argument is the function to be applied on the columns selected.

I noticed that some other answers used `all_of()` inside `across`, which is not necessary in this case. It's only used when you want to make sure **ALL** columns supplied in `all_of()` are present in the current dataframe. If any of the column in `all_of()` is not present, it will throw an error.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(c(b, g), as.factor))

# A tibble: 2 × 10
      a b         c     d     e     f g         h     i     j
  <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 1         2     1     1     1 1         1     8     1
2     1 2         1     5     1     1 2         6     1     1
```